# Using an int array of varying sizes in an object

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I am pretty new to this but I am trying to create a class that declares an int array as an attribute.

DataHousing.h

```
class DataHousing {
private:
    // ATTRIBUTES
    int fileContents[count];
    int count;
```

DataHousing.cpp

```
// CLASS METHOD IMPLEMENTATIONS
#include "DataHousing.h"

// CONSTRUCTORS
DataHousing::DataHousing() {
    this->fileContents = NULL;
    this->count = 0;
}
```

The array will vary in size depending on the amount of numbers that are contained in a separate file.  So, one file will be read in and stored in an array using dynamic memory which may have 500 different numbers.  But, another file may be read in that has 100,000 different numbers.

I have a method in the class that will count the numbers in each file and then populate the count variable.

How do I initialize the array if I do not know what the size will be?

Comment: Just use a `std::vector<>` instead

Comment: @Frank  I have never learned vectors.

Comment: Well this is a good time to learn about `std::vector`, because that is the tool in C++ that is used to do this job.

Comment: and `int fileContents[count];` is non-standard c++.